# Unable to perform insertion for a model having list of objects in Asp.net Mvc codefirst

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on creating a simple movie Db and performing crud operations on that,using Asp.net MVC (Entity Framework) Code first approach.
I have the following models:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string  Sex { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
}
```

Actor Model

```
public class Actor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

Movie Model

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Plot { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string YearOfRelease { get; set; }

    public string Poster { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

created a controller as MoviesController using the option : Controllers with views,using EF.

Heres the situation:

The create view did not have Input form element for actors.

So i wanted to add actors for a movie so i created the following ViewModel:

```
public class NewMovieViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Actor> Actors { get; set; }

    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
}
```

modified the controller with the following :

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var actors = db.Actors.Include(a => a.Person).ToList(); 
    var ViewModel = new NewMovieViewModel
    {
        Actors = actors
    };
    return View(ViewModel);
}
```

Added a multiselect listbox in the view :

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Movie.Actors,new MultiSelectList (Model.Actors,"Id","Person.Name") , new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

So how do i proceed in order to add a movie.

I tried with the following controller:

```
public ActionResult Create( NewMovieViewModel movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Movies.Add(movie.Movie);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(movie);
}
```

But the Count of actors in the NewMovieViewModel is 0.

I have searched for answers and couldn't figure way out.
I dont know how to proceed.

---

Comment: Change the model to `@model NewMovieViewModel` and POST action method to `public ActionResult Create(NewMovieViewModel model)`, then perform mapping viewmodel to model and insert to DB.

Comment: Thank you for your response,The actors count in NewMovieModel is 0, when i have selected couple of actors from the listbox.So the actor ids is not available in the NewViewModel

Answer (score 0):

your view is stronglly typed so it will take same as you supplied to view
  so form method look like

```
public ActionResult Create( NewMovieViewModel movie)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Movies.Add(movie.movie);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(movie);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.I tried this. I am fetching Multiple Ids from the listbox by displaying the Person(who is an Actor) Name. Due to which the following validation error is thrown  "The value '1,2' is invalid.".

Comment: i you using multiselect you need to get value in string array not in model type..change you listBox for string array